# How to determine $\sigma$-Algebra?

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$=$\Bbb R$ and $\mathcal R$ = {$A \subseteq \Omega  : A \cap \Bbb R_+ $is Borel-set and $A \cap \Bbb R_- \in${$\emptyset, \Bbb R_-$}  }

What is the $\sigma$-Algebra generated by $\mathcal R$?

I have no idea how to find it. We always get those weird looking sets $\mathcal R$ and I don't know how to find their $\sigma$-Algebra's.

Is there a method or formula of how to determine a $\sigma$-Algebra?

Comment: Is it not $A\cap\mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $A\cap\mathbb{R}_{-}$ instead of $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}_{+}$
and $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}_{-}$?

Comment: yes, sorry for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\mathcal{R}\cup\left\{ R\cup\left\{ 0\right\} \mid R\in\mathcal{R}\right\} $
is a $\sigma$-algebra. (Check that and draw conclusions).

Comment: I forgot to tell that $0$ is in $\Bbb R_-$. So is $\mathcal R$ its own $\sigma$-Algebra?

Comment: Yes $\mathcal{R}$ it is a sigma-algebra (check this and let me know if you come to another conclusion) hence $\sigma\left(\mathcal{R}\right)=\mathcal{R}$